# Mysqlclient fails to install

Tags: python, mysql, django, pip

I am trying to install mysqlclient on mac to use mysql in a django project. I have made sure that setup tools is installed and that mysql connector c is installed as well. I keep getting the error `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in`. This is my first django project since switching from rails. Is there something I am missing? I am using python 3 and I use `pip install mysqlclient`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by running `pip install mysql`. I do not understand why this worked because I already had MySQL installed on my system and had been using it.

I am going to assume it is because Python uses environments and MySQL wasn't installed in the environment but I would like to know for sure.